# How to create a separate secondary phonebook / contact list

Tags: samsung, contacts

Here's what I need. I run a business, I use my personal Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S8) for 100% of my calls. It's not a problem. But I have a lot of clients whose numbers I don't have memorized. I could put a hundred contacts in my personal phone so I would know who's calling, but, I don't want to fill up my phone's contact list with people I only talk to occasionally.

When I look at my contact list, I want to see my friends and family only. Is there an app that will handle sort of a 'secondary phonebook' with business contacts only, that will still work with caller ID?

And if you are going to comment 'you need a second phone for business stuff', don't bother. That's not what I want to do, and that's not what I'm asking.  This is a question about whether there is a particular Android app that will solve my problem (or an Android setting), not anything else.

Comment: 1. Create a group , say business as explained [here](https://recomhub.com/blog/how-to-manage-groups-on-galaxy-s8-and-galaxy-s8-plus/) . Add members as explained  2. Hide / unhide contacts as explained [here](https://wikitechsolutions.com/5012/how-to-hide-or-unhide-phonebook-contacts-in-android)  - there would be minor variations as it is for a different device. 3. Hide business group to only see family / friends, unhide when you want to contact them

Comment: Why don't you try Shelter app from fdroid. What it does is kind of turns your phone into two phones. Separate apps, separate data. In my opinion that's exactly what you want. And the fun part is you'll receive the calls normally :) Realized now.. im too late..

Answer (score 2):

I have saved separate phone contact lists as vCard files-one for business and another for private use. another for frequently dialed numbers (hybrid of both pvt+biz). It is tedious but depending on my need i load(import) one from my collections above. Hope this method helps.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I could find is [OpenContacts](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/opencontacts.open.com.opencontacts/). It's a completely separated contact book that comes with good integration, but without letting your contact information slip through it's own container. No contacts will be shared to other apps like WhatsApp.

It's my choice when it comes to handling business contacts while ensuring GDPR compliance. I even use [NetGuard](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/eu.faircode.netguard/) to disable internet for OpenContacts just to be safe.

Quote from F-Droid store:

> **OpenContacts**
>
> ***Hide contacts away from apps stealing your contacts information***
>
> Even though we are not having any problem sharing our mobile number with all third parties, people in our phone book might have. We should not be sharing their contact information online. So, keep your contacts safe in a different database.
>
> This app saves contacts in its own database seperate from android contacts. This way no other app would be able to access contacts.
> Can be used in place of your default phone(dialer) app. It can import contacts from vCard files. So we can export Android contacts and import into this app.
>
> Maintains call log as well coz Android call log app would not be able to show name of contact. Also shows the person's name upon recieving call

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google contacts app with two Google accounts and swap between the accounts easily as necessary.
([Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts) is a link to the Google contacts app.)
Or if you're using a Galaxy S8, you can have separate contacts in the secure folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't find an app to fix it so I decided to create one.
You can check it out  [Secondary Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nothingapps.com.secondarycontacts)

It's an entirely separate contacts list that can't be read by other apps. Has caller ID too and you can import/export contacts to and from the main contacts app